# Limit the data that will be shown on the table and add pages for the next data. a gridview like table

Tags: php, html

i have my sql server connection

```
$sql_exp = "select * from dbo.PC inner join dbo.FA_PC on dbo.PC.PCID = dbo.FA_PC.PCID WHERE UserID is NOT NULL order by dbo.fa_pc.PCID"; 
   $sql_exp1= "select * from dbo.users inner join dbo.FA_PC on dbo.users.UserID = dbo.FA_PC.UserID order by dbo.fa_pc.PCID";
    $sql_exp2 = "select * from dbo.FA_Type inner join dbo.FA_PC on dbo.FA_Type.FA_TypeID = dbo.FA_PC.FA_TypeID order by dbo.fa_pc.PCID"; 
   $rs = $conn->Execute($sql_exp);
    $rs1 = $conn->Execute($sql_exp1);
  $rs2 = $conn->Execute($sql_exp2);
   echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' id='rounded-corner'><tr><th>Desktop Number</th><th>Employee</th><th><p align=left>Fixed Asset Accountability</p></th></tr>";
   echo '<select name="print">'; 
   echo "<option value=".$rs->Fields("PC_Number")."> </option>";
   while (!$rs->EOF) {
       set_time_limit(0);


       echo "<td>CP # <br>".$rs->Fields("PC_Number")."</td>";   
       echo "<td>".$rs1->Fields("EmployeeName")."</td>";    
      echo "<td>".$rs2->Fields("FA_Type")."</td><tr>";  

      $rs->MoveNext();
      $rs1->MoveNext();
      $rs2->MoveNext();
   }
   echo "</table>";   
   $rs->Close();
   $rs1->Close();
   $rs2->Close();
```

so this code will just print every single data in my database , around 100 details and how could i just limit the data input by 10, 20, 30,40,50,100 and just add few next and previous page link for the remaining data which is mos likely a gridview like form

Comment: checkout any pagination article -- [this](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm) is for MySQL but the PHP code is the same

Comment: is it applicable to sql server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a `LIMIT`. e.g for page 1 `LIMIT 0, 10`, page 2 `LIMIT 10,10`, page 3 'LIMIT 20, 10`, so on and so fort.....

where `LIMIT 0(page), 10(max content shows)`